# not geting address with help of lat and long in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am trying to get address using `reverse geocoding`.
but there is some problem in `geocoder.geocode({...})` line. even normal alert message also not display.

```
 function initialize() { 
 var mapOptions = { 
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.0171240, 72.5330533),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
    var input=e.latLng;
    var lat = parseFloat(input.lat());
    var lng = parseFloat(input.lng());
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           alert(results[1].formatted_address);
        }
      });
    });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below line inside initialize() function.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```